# How to deal with slow large word files?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a large (~245mb) word file with several pictures and it is running extremely sluggishly, freezing for a minute or two frequently.

I use this file to store my university notes for different topics of a certain course. I want to be able to use the ctrl+f feature, and so I don't want to split the word file up into different files, as if I do I won't be able to ctrl+f the whole lot to find the relevent content.

Are there any ways to speed up performance (in exchange for say aesthetics like you could on old editions of windows changing the task bar to grey instead of the glassy effect)? Or any other ways I could continue to use a single large word doc?

I have found some relief by using the draft view instead of print layout.

Would buying a new and better computer help? My CPU and Memory are only at 60 and 85% respectively (during the freeze) so I am wondering if throwing a better computer at word will do anything, as the CPU and RAM are not currently being maxed out.

Comment: I have found that using draft view + saving as a doc instead of docx (which allows pictures to be visible in draft view) to be a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't insert large images into a Word document, the images are stored as bitmaps.

Reduce size with an application like IRFANView to the pixel size you really need, instead of a 15 megapixel when the display is only 2 megapixels or less (for most users).

You can also insert links to your pictures instead of embedding the image files in document.

Comment: Good idea, I didn't think of that. I have a 4K monitor and constantly use screen grabs of my lecture slides in my note-taking so that has probably compounded the issue.

Comment: http://labs.russell.wisc.edu/hub/files/2014/01/How_to_Compress_Images_in_Microsoft_Word_Documents.pdf

Comment: Would you look at that. I thought I would have to get in there and do it manually, one by one. It trimmed 50 mb off it!

Comment: THere's a ton of ways to make Windows lean and mean. But I dont have time now.